# Перегрузка операторов: как сделать срез списка?

Tags: python

Добрых суток. Есть класс с контейнером. Хочу сделать срез с экземпляра класса, как если бы обратился к списку. Как это можно реализовать не наследуясь от класса list, а возможно, с помощью магических методов?

```
class L:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lst = []

l = L()
l[:]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Срез реализуется через метод `__getitem__` (тот же метод, что и для взятия элемента по индексу). При выполнении среза в этот метод передается специальный объект класса `slice`. Пример реализации:

```
class L:
    def __init__(self, lst=None):
        if not lst:
            self.__lst = []
        else:
            self.__lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            # Создание нового объекта данного класса с элементами среза внутреннего списка
            return self.__class__(self.__lst[item.start:item.stop:item.step])
            # или return self.__class__(self.__lst[item]))
        else:
            return L.__lst[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'L(%r)' % self.__lst

x = L(list(range(10)))
print(x)  # Вывод: L([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print(x[2:5])  # Вывод: L([2, 3, 4])
```

Присваивание срезу и удаление среза реализуется аналогично с помощью методов `__setitem__` и `__delitem__`.

Доп. информация: [Habrahabr: Всё, что Вы хотели знать о слайсах](https://habrahabr.ru/post/89456/)

Answer (score 2):

```
class L:
    def __getitem__(self, i): # Перегружаем []
        if isinstance(i, slice): # Проверяем на срез
            ... # Необходимые действия
        return self.__lst[i]
```